# How to mock Mono.create

Tags: groovy, reactive-programming, spock, project-reactor

I'm using the spock framework and need to return a mocked Mono from a Mono.create(..)

I've tried:

```groovy
GroovyMock(Mono)
```

as well as

```groovy
GroovyMock(Mono, global:true)
1 * Mono.create(_ as MonoSink) >> Mono.just(returnedValue)
```

But I get the message that there were too few assertions for the above code.

Here is the actual Mono.create code

```groovy
Mono.create{ sink -> 
    myAPISoap.getStuffAsync(
            username, 
            password, 
            info, 
            { outputFuture -> 
                try {
                    sink.success(outputFuture.get())
                } catch(Exception e){
                    sink.error(e)
                } 
            }
    )
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into the Reactor manual's [testing section](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#testing)?

Comment: @kriegaex yes, but to use stepverifier, I still need to return a known mono.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spock, you can only mock [static methods](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.3/all_in_one.html#_mocking_static_methods) of Groovy classes, not Java classes. You can use [PowerMock](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/mockito#mocking-static-method)(ito) for Java classes in this case. Then your problem can be solved as follows:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Mono.class)
public class MonoTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        //given:
        PowerMockito.spy(Mono.class);
        Mockito.when(Mono.create(...)).thenReturn(null);

        //when:
        Mono<?> mono = Mono.create(...);

        //then:
        PowerMockito.verifyStatic(Mono.class, Mockito.times(1));
        Mono.create(...);

        //assertions
    }
}
```

Comment: You could also use PowerMock from within Spock, by the way.

Comment: @kriegaex yes, it’s possible but Spock will be of no use because Powermock doesn’t have special integration with Spock. And I think in some cases there could be some problems due to bytecode manipulation by Powermock. However, in this particular case the test will look absolutely the same...without Spock features

Comment: The question is about Spock (thus the tag) and Powermock works in connection with Spock, a special integration is not needed. So I think it will be of use at least with respect to not having to mix Spock with plain JUnit tests and using two languages (Java and Groovy) for testing, assuming that the OP already uses Spock. Besides, I generally think that whenever Powermock seems to be necessary it is a reason to refactor code, not to use Powermock. But that is also out of scope of the question.

Comment: @kriegaex thanks for the comment. But the question is also about _"...need to return a mocked Mono from a Mono.create(..)"_. Thus the answer... Also, I believe I've made my point about integration in my previous comment. And yes, I agree on necessity of Powermock being the indicator of not so good design in most situations and the provided Spock doc is clear about that. But this was not the question. I also hope that my answer helped the OP anyway, at least wrt Spock and existence of other possibilities

Comment: I had to figure out the right configuration to get Spock and Powermock working together.  Here is what is working:
implementation('org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.5.5')
testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
testImplementation('io.projectreactor:reactor-test')
testImplementation 'org.spockframework:spock-core:1.3-groovy-2.5'
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.23.0'
testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:2.0.2'
testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:2.0.2'

Answer (score 1):

*Dmitry Khamitov* already showed you how to use PowerMock in Java + JUnit, I want to complete the picture by providing an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in Groovy + Spock for your convenience:

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q56064582;

import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

public class ReactorSample {
  public Mono<String> doSomething() {
    return Mono.just("foo");
  }
}
```

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q56064582

import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunnerDelegate
import org.spockframework.runtime.Sputnik
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono
import spock.lang.Specification

import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyString
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.when

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(Sputnik.class)
@PrepareForTest([Mono.class])
class ReactorSampleTest extends Specification {
  def "test me"() {
    given:
    def dummy = Mono.just("power-mocked")
    mockStatic(Mono.class)
    when(Mono.just(anyString())).thenReturn(dummy)
    def sut = new ReactorSample()

    expect:
    sut.doSomething() == dummy
  }
}
```

You can easily adapt it to other static `Mono` methods.