# Stubbing or mocking static methods in Java with Spock

Tags: java, spock

Is it possible to mock static methods in java with spock? I know it is possible to mock static groovy methods but can't get this working for Java methods.

Comment: Spying a static method in a java class isnt something spock natively supports. Is a refactor not an option for you here?

Comment: Refactoring not an option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You need PowerMockito for that. Refactor the class or alternatively wrap the static call in a protected method and stub it out as a spy.

Comment: Correct answer. :-) Besides, IMO the need for PowerMock (PM) is a code smell. So I always recommend to refactor or wrap instead of using PM, but for what it is worth, [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56105180/1082681) shows how you can use PM from Spock.

Answer (score 2):

First, one of the best/worst solutions to this question is Powermock. Yes, Powermock will give you the ability to mock static methods. You mock the method, your test passes and you are totally under the impression you just landed on the Moon (just kidding). I will be the first one to confess that I am 100% guilty of this practice and I deserve a stiff sentence for my lack of thinking.

What are you actually accomplishing by using Powermock to mock static methods??

You are perpetuating an anti-pattern that probably already exists in abundance in whatever application you are working on. Among many negative side effects of this, is that other developers will come in, look at this code and think it's okay to continue implementing this solution in whatever use cases they are working on.

My take is this. I started out with mocking static methods, but it never felt right. Too much setup and configuration before you even get started writing the test.

What I found is that by just creating a helper class that I can just inject with  a mock (depending on your situation) in the class under test with a method that returns the type that the static instance method does, will allow me to mock that method and therefore avoid Powermock. Also, production code in this use case is not impacted.

By now, I am now using Spock 100%, but the same principle can be accomplished with JUnit.

If you find yourself relying on Powermock in your application, think about eliminating this dependency. This is one of the worst open source libraries that actually provided a solution to a problem, but it never addresses and proposed a solution to the root cause of the problem.

Comment: This is kind of the more verbose version of my comment from last year. I almost completely agree, only one small detail needs explanation. You say, "production code in this use case is not impacted". Well, it is because you need to refactor and replace all direct static method calls by calls to the wrapper class, maybe also instantiating it if it is not a singleton or getting it from a factory method which then smells pretty "static" again. Maybe you want to elaborate on the design pattern used there with some real or pseudo code. Then notify me and I will delete or alter my comment. :-)

Comment: Yes actually I stand corrected on kriegaex comments.In a production environment, the call to the helper method would actually execute the real static method. In a unit test case, the mock would be returned.

Comment: Anyway, your suggestion makes sense and refactoring for better design without changing functionality is what tests help you do fearlessly if you have good coverage. Automated tests are mainly a design tool anyway, IMO. And refactoring has never been easier than with modern IDEs, especially sophisticated stuff like IntelliJ IDEA's structural search and replace.